# Remove transparency from d3heatmap

Tags: r, d3heatmap

I realized a heatmap using d3heatmap function but I get transparent color. How can I remove this transparency?

[image]

Moreover, as you can see I have a huge number of rows and the label were overlapped. Is there a way to format the label ? It's fine also if only some labels will be shown.

my code:

```
library("d3heatmap")

d3heatmap(b, col = coul, k_row =4, k_col = 4,show_grid = TRUE, key=TRUE)
```

Comment: Presumably you could set the `labRow` property with a vector of empty strings and the row names you want to use?  Or `cexRow` to set the scaling of the text.  https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/d3heatmap/man/d3heatmap.html

Comment: Already read this link, but nothing regarding the transaprency. Some suggestions?